# initilize unordered_map with a vector in c++

Tags: c++, initialization, unordered-map

I simply would like to initizlize an unordered_map with a vector.

When I have tried the code below, the code does not compile.

What is the shortest syntax to initilize unordered_map with a vector? How would you implement following method without using loop.

```
unordered_map<int, int> convertToMap(const vector<int>& v) 
{
  unordered_map<int, int> umap(v.begin(), v.end());

  return umap;
}
```

I have found some resources, and I have tried to initialize through a range, but it does not worked either!

[initialize-unordered-map](http://thispointer.com/different-ways-to-initialize-an-unordered_map/)

Comment: How are going to decide which elements of vector should represent keys and which values?

Comment: what is the key(s) of your vector?

Comment: lets say v[i]+5 is key and v[i] value

Comment: Even if you don't use the loop - the library in which you hide it will.

Answer (score 7):

> How to initialize unordered_map with vector?

If your vector contains pairs of elements, so that one could be interpreted as key and one as value then you can use range initialization:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>


int main() 
{

    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> v = { {1,10}, {2,20}, {3,30} };
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map(v.begin(), v.end());

    std::cout << map[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above prints: 20